# How to handle the EXCEPT message?

Tags: python, exception

I am working with Python.
In my program I am using "try:" and "except:". Inside the "except" I want to send an email telling that some error has occurred and the action could not be executed, but I also like to add which is exactly the error.

Is there any way I can print the error message or use it in a variable?

I hope I made myself clear

Thanks a lot

Comment: Did you read about exception handling in the [Python tutorial](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/errors.html) and the [Python Wiki](http://wiki.python.org/moin/HandlingExceptions)?

Comment: In addition to suggestions on Python documentation, I would recommend reading [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Python < 2.6

```
try:
    ...
except Exception, e:
    print(e)
```

In Python >= 2.6

```
try:
    ...
except Exception as e:
    print(e)
```

This will give you the Exception message.

If you want the full traceback you can use the following:

```
import traceback
try:
    ...
except Exception, e:
    print traceback.format_exc()
```

Comment: The `except exception, e` syntax has been deprecated in Python 2 as well. Python 2.6 and newer support the `except Exception as e:` syntax.

Answer (score 2):

Python >= 2.6

```
try:
    ...
except Exception as e:
    print(e)
```

Python < 2.6

```
try:
    ...
except Exception, e:
    print(e)
```

it will print the actuall message.

Comment: The same syntax works in Python 2.6 and 2.7 as well. No need to look at the traceback module there. For Python 2.5 and earlier, the `except Exception, e:` syntax is used.